# Limit of a composition, given convergence

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Edit: after the comments and suggestions received by other users, I have updated the question to make it more rigorous and less ambiguous.

Let $\{f_{k}\}_{k}, \{g_{k}\}_{k}$ be two sequences of continuous functions, where $$f_{k}:\mathbb{R}^{p}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}\quad\text{and}\quad g_{k}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{p}.$$
Assume that $f_{k}\to f$ uniformily and that $(g_{k}\circ f_{k})\to h$ uniformily, for some $h\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}^{p};\mathbb{R}^{p})$. The maps $g_{k}$, instead, are only known to converge pointwise to some measurable map $g:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{p}$.

Finally, we also know that $\|f_{k}(x)\|,\|g_{k}(y)\|,\|f(x)\|,\|g(y)\|\le1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{p}$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Is it true that $h \equiv g\circ f$ everywhere?

Comment: It makes no sens to ask everywhere to a merely $L^1$ function. If you accept to ask "almost everywhere" then $h = g \circ f$ is easy to get.

Comment: Fair enough. Let's say we replace $g$ with $\lim\inf_{k} g_{k}$, which is defined everywhere. According to your comment, then $h=g\circ f$ a.e., meaning also that $g\circ f$ admits a continuous modification? But can we get equality everywhere? Or maybe we can find a counter example?

Comment: The question is now trivial because the pointwise limit is unique provided the codomain is Hausdorff. To see this just use the uniqueness of the limit in $\mathbb R^p$.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not true. The two are in fact different limits: by definition we have $h(x)=\lim_{k} g_{k}(f_{k}(x))$, while instead $g(f(x))=\lim_{k} g_{k}(\lim_{n} f_{n}(x))$ given the pointwise convergence.

If the $g_{k}$ are Lipschitz continuous and admit a common Lipschitz constant, then the statement follows. Otherwise this is not true. See my own answer for a counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the statement is false, so I will post a counterexample for the sake of completeness. Consider the real-valued maps
$$g_{k}(x)=x^{k},\quad f_{k}(x)=1-1/k,$$
over the interval $[0,1]$. We consider the latter domain, instead of $\mathbb{R}$, just for simplicity (the idea can be easily adapted).

Then $f_{k}\to f\equiv1$ uniformily, while $g_{k}\to g$ pointwise, where $g(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1)$ and $g(1)=1$. In particular, the sequence $g_{k}\circ f_{k}$ converges uniformily to the constant map $h\equiv 1/e$, but $g\circ f\equiv1\neq h.$

Answer (score 0):

Your claim "$h = g \circ f$ everywhere" is wrong by the very definition of the objects you introduced.

The function $g$ is introduced as an almost everywhere limit, and you even wrote $g \in L^1$. It's then a *class* of functions, which is also called an *almost everywhere* defined function. Then if you wish to look at $g \circ f$ what you have to do is the following : the mapping
$$ 
(\varphi , \psi) \longmapsto \varphi \circ \psi
$$
respects the a.e. identification, meaning that if $\varphi_1 = \varphi_2$ and $\psi_1 = \psi_2$ almost everywhere, then $\varphi_1 \circ \psi_1 = \varphi_2 \circ \psi_2$ almost everywhere. This means that you can define the composition for *equivalence class* of functions saying that the composition of two classes is the class of the composition of any of the representatives. What I just wrote explains that the last definition does not depend on the representative so that there is a hope it is meaningful.

So the very definition of $g \circ f$ is to be a class of function. In general we cannot hope any better: pick $f(x) = x$ and $g$ a class of function, in full generality I don't know how to find a representative of $g \circ f = g$ without using Zorn's lemma.

In your precise situation there is a way to have better than just a class of functions: $h = g \circ f$ a.e. (why?) with $h$ continuous. Hence $g \circ f$ has a continuous representative, which is often translated in "$g \circ f$ is continuous", and this representative happens to be $h$. This is the meaning you should provide to "$h = g \circ f$ everywhere".

NB1: your other claim "$\liminf_k g_k$, which is defined everywhere" is also wrong in full generality. Just take $g_k = g$ a class of function and try to figure out the *definition* of $\liminf_k g_k$.

NB2: you may want to convince yourself that a measurable mapping has at most one continuous representative.

Comment: Thank you @blamethelag, the way I framed the question was indeed poorly chosen. I have now modified it so that we do not need to talk about classes of functions. Please let me know if you have any insights, many thanks!